# Program for custom UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I have to start working on a project that involves making an application with user friendly interface. I can do all of the programming in Visual Studio by making a c# application but I don't know how to customize the interface.
It has to be quite interactive..like dragging things to a bin or list, customized buttons and menus (or something like that).

Could you please refer me to a program that I could use to achieve that?

Comment: A program to achieve building a UI for a .NET application?  Something like... Visual Studio?

Comment: Entire books are written on this subject.  (The FAQ mentions that if an entire book could be written on the subject it is not an appropriate question for SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WPF Application`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb820878(v=vs.90).aspx

In Visual Studio you can start with creating project

[image]

Some Patterns around WPF Application (Best practises) :

`Prism` : http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a basic howto on C# forms. Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb820885%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).